# LIKE clause that will select '2' but not '12' from a string of characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a legacy database that includes a field 'User_Defined' containing a string describing which projects each record belongs to.  The project IDs are comma-separated numbers in that string.  For example, records might include:

```
2
12
22
2,12
2,8,10,12
2,12,20,120,220
```

The current query is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT tbl_species.Species_ID, 
    tbl_species.Common_Name, 
    tbl_species.User_Defined
FROM tbl_species
WHERE User_Defined LIKE '%2';
```

In this case, the query of course would return all the records that contain '2' anywhere in the string. I'm picking on 2 here, but it can be any number passed in via a PHP variable.

My question is how can I craft the query so that it returns only those records containing 2 but not 12, 22, 120, etc.?

BTW, I realize that the proper way to fix this would be to create a lookup table to handle this relation, but if I could patch this until the next redesign, it would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', User_Defined)
```

Comment: That worked when the passed variable was 2, but didn't handle when searching for 12. I forgot to mention that I also need to handle the other situations (e.g., searching for '12')-- my bad!

Comment: @dwardio: To search for 12 you need to change the `'2'` in the query to `'12'`.

Comment: @MarkByers: Right.  Seems like your answer should work, but when I change the 2 to 12, I'm not getting the all the records containing 12.  I'm taking a closer look to see exactly what's missing...

Comment: @MarkByers:  Confirmed-- FIND_IN_SET('12', User_Defined) is returning only the records that only contain '12' and missing the case of '2,12' and '12,13' and so forth...

Comment: @dwardio: Sure? `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('12', '12,13')` gives 1 for me.

Comment: @MarkByers: Yes. Running `SELECT Common_Name, User_Defined FROM tbl_species WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12', User_Defined);` is returning 2 records instead of the 10 that contain 12 somewhere in the User_Defined string.  Drat!

Comment: @dwardio: Perhaps there are some spaces or other invisible characters in your data.

Comment: @MarkByers: Bingo.  There were indeed spaces in the "missing" results.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Add a leading and trailing comma to the column being searched, then search for your value surrounded by commas.

```
...
WHERE CONCAT(',', User_Defined, ',') LIKE '%,2,%';
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for '2', but changing it to '12' returns only the records that only contain '12' and missing the case of '2,12' and '12,13' and so forth...

Comment: @dwardio are there spaces after the commas? Otherwise I can't see how this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User_Defined LIKE '2,%' OR User_Defined='2' OR User_Defined LIKE '%,2' OR User_Defined LIK E '%,2,%'
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, me too. But the question explicitely asked for LIKE.